# How will light rays behave if they enter lens vertically,i.e. from top?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

What will happen to light rays if they enter convex lens from pointed side or from plane side of concave lens. See image for clarification.

[image: image of ques]

Comment: The laws of refraction (Snell's law) are the same for any binary interface.

Comment: The light rays that your diagram shows entering the concave lens almost certainly would be striking an _unpolished_ surface in real life.

Comment: Presumably the lenses have an axis of symmetry (vertical on your picture).  Are the incident rays in the same plane as that axis?

Comment: @MisterMak Assume they are in same plane as that of axis. By the way what changes would be observed if they are not?